# Camel RabbitMQ concurrentConsumers and threadPoolsize for messages that must be processed in sequence

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

I have a camel route processing messages from a RabbitMQ endpoint. I am keeping the defaults for concurrentConsumers (1) and threadPoolSize(10).

I am relative new to RabbitMQ, and still do not quite understand the relationship between the concurrentConsumer and threadPoolSize properties. The messages in my queues need to be processed in sequence, which I think shall be achieved by using a single consumer. However, will using a threadPoolSize value greater than one cause messages to be processed in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

The default value is 10 (source : https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/rabbitmq-component.html)

It won't affect your concurrency. That means the only one consumer will have 10 threads available to use for the process. You can check at **exclusiveConsumer** if you want only one consumer shared between all your apps (needed if you could have multiple apps targeting the queue)